# Does System.currentTimeMillis represent UTC time?

Tags: java

Does `System.currentTimeMillis()` represent UTC time or local system time?

Comment: see http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t145337-system-currenttimemillis.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

UTC - it's the number of milliseconds since midnight on January 1st 1970 UTC (modulo leap seconds, potentially).

Obviously it's reliant on the local system *clock*, but it doesn't depend on the local system *time zone*.

(It's a shame that the Javadoc isn't clearer on this, admittedly.)

Comment: so at same time,  `System.currentTimeInMillis` would be globally same (everywhere & in all timezones) right ?

Comment: @user: Assuming an accurate clock on all the machines, yes.

Comment: @Jon Skeet is there an elegant way of converting `System.currentTimeMillis` to the correct time zone of the device?

Comment: @EugenevanderMerwe: Well you can use `java.util.Calendar`, and set the time zone and the time. Personally I'd recommend Joda Time instead. You shouldn't usually be trying to get a `long` as a "milliseconds since midnight on January 1st in some other time zone" though - that's rarely a helpful concept IMO.

Comment: Java doc is like your answer... it can't just say yes or no ? :)

Answer (score 3):

UTC according to oracle.com.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis

"currentTimeMillis

Returns:

the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC."